# type object in Python

Tags: python, call, metaclass

In Python, I reckon object(s) are available for the type class and the object name is same as class name which is type.
I have a question regarding this... When we create classes using type(classname,base_class,att_dict), actually the **call**() method in type is getting invoked.
This will eventually produce an object of the given class (eg: `type("some_class", (),{}`).

In this statement, `type("some_class", (),{})`, the type is the object (of the class type)
Here, by using the type object the **call**() is invoked.

I reckon type() is a class method as well. So on this case, ideally it can be invoked by the following too:

```
type.__call__("some_class", (),{})
```

But this is erroring out.

```
TypeError: descriptor '__call__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'
```

At the same time, the below works well.

```
>>> class sample:
...     @classmethod
...     def __call__(cls,a):
...         return a*a
...
>>> sample.__call__(10)
100
```

So I am confused about the above error message.. like: where my understanding is incorrect?
Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: `type` *is a type itself*. The type of types. "his will eventually produce an object of the given class" what do you mean by the "given class"? `type` *creates a class*. "type" is a synonym for "class" in Python. In any case, your idea that `type.__call__` is a class method is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several parts that we need to discuss one by one.

Your confusion starts from this sentence:

> I reckon type() (or `__call__` more specifically) is a class method as well.

No `__call__` is a normal method (aka instance method). In instance methods if you call it from the class, you need to pass the first parameter. (This is the behavior of [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) objects - methods are descriptors).

With that being said, we have another thing which is [special attribute lookup for magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) (`__call__` is a magic method.)

Which says whenever you call `type(something)`, Python is going to call it like: `type(type).__call__(type, something)`. If you evaluate the first part(type of `type` is `type`) you'll end up with `type.__call__(type, something)`.

So:

```py
type("some_class", (), {})
# or
type.__call__(type, "some_class", (), {})
```

Another thing that may be a bit obscure is that `type` is the instance of itself. That means when you put parenthesis in front of `type`, the `__call__` of itself is going to be executed. "like a normal method".

```
type metaclass   -->   custom class   -->   instance of the custom class


type:
    instance "and" class of itself. class of the custom class
custom class:
    instance of type. class of 'instance of the custom class'
instance of the custom class:
    instance of the custom class.
```

**Note:** If I could draw well, I would draw another arrow from `'type metaclass` to again `'type metaclass'`. It has this relationship with itself.

Now you may ask: You said `type` is itself an instance so in `type.__call__` aren't we calling it from an instance? why it's not bound?

To answer that I highly recommend to take a look at this [attribute lookup workflow](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance). It found `__call__` name in the type/class of the `type`(which is itself) but it's a *non-data* descriptor. So it checks the instance's namespace which is again `type`'s namespace. It finds it and invokes it as it is. So no bounding behavior!

---

> This will eventually produce an object of the "given"(?) class

Let's make it clear. This will eventually produce an object which is itself a class(a type) and its name is `"some_class"`. This is the instance of the `type` metaclass.

---

> At the same time, the below works well.

Yes because you deliberately made it a classmethod. The `__call__` of the `type` metaclass is not a classmethod.

##### Answer to the question in comment:

> Just to confirm my understanding... The 'type' class is NOT stored as object (like an user defined class is stored as an instance of 'type').. but 'type' class has a built-in instance called 'type' (same as its class name). am I correct ?

No. There are no two distinct `type` objects in Python. `type` is an object (like any other objects in Python) which is both an instance of itself, "and" at the same time, it is the class of itself. There is one single `type` object. With `is` operator and `id()` you can confirm it:

```py
print(type is type(type))  # True

id_of_type = id(type)
id_of_type_of_type = id(type(type))
print(id_of_type)          # 94651554023840
print(id_of_type_of_type)  # 94651554023840
```

Comment: Thanks S.B. Your great explanation made things clear to me.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding... The 'type' class is NOT stored as object (like an user defined class is stored as an instance of 'type').. but 'type' class has a built-in instance called 'type' (same as its class name). am I correct ? thanks

Comment: @user3103957 You can check the updated answer now

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it implies that the type class and type object are the same. When initially Python loads into memory, the 'type' object (let us call this as A) is created. Whenever interpreter comes across an user defined class, it creates another 'type' object using the already existing 'type' object (A).. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user3103957 Since the name "object" refers to "everything" in Python, we tend to give other names to what we see so that we can describe it a little bit more. It makes more sense to the reader. A metaclass is an object, a user defined class is an object, an instance of the user defined class is object, a function is an object and etc.

Comment: @user3103957 `type` is an object with the all mentioned behavior. Whenever Python encounters `class` keyword, it will create a new object which we call it a type or a class. This class is an instance of the `type`. IOW `type` is its metaclass.

Comment: Thanks S.B for your kind feedback!!  I really appreciate it.